# Visual studio 2013: Can an "Alert" be sent for whenever an automated test fails in Test Manager?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, automated-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2013 Premium and use Alerts (Team -> Project Alerts -> Advanced Alerts Management) to send an e-mail to my inbox whenever certain work items are modified.

I am wondering if it's possible to get this kind of Alert to work with Automated Test Cases (i.e. test cases which are executed automatically via build-deploy-test) which have failed?

It doesn't have to work with Alerts - I'm just after any mechanism that provides this behavior.

Thanks!

-IQ

Answer (score 0):

If you are using *build-deploy-test* mechanism to run automated test all you have to do is to setup alert for this build.

The build will fail if deployment failed and it will be "Partially succeeded" if deployment was successful but at least one test fails.

You can find this kind of alerts in Team -> Project Alerts -> Advanced Alerts Management.

Comment: Hi Elena, thanks for answering my question many moons ago!   For some reason my original queries were not working and now they do - we recently updated our tfs server to 2013 so this may have made a difference.

Comment: However, it is unfortunate that the build "Partially succeeded" message is the only way to tell that the automated tests have failed.  I was hoping for something more granular like an e-mail saying which tests have failed, but alas something like that doesn't exist yet according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348601/sending-out-email-alert-when-a-test-case-is-pass-or-fail

Comment: Unfortunately, no detailed information is provided with these built-in alerts.
But these details are just two clicks away ;-)
If you want to have this sent via email though, the only way I know is to extend Build-Deploy-Test workflow by a custom activity that would get this information via TFS API.